# Personalized axis range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I have values going these kinds of range (400k to 600 million)

[image]

And I would like to create a comprehensive y-axis on a D3 plot.
If I use a log scale, all the variations in the huge numbers are erased, If I use a linearScale, all variations in the small numbers is also erased.

Therefore I thought of doing two-axis (one over the other like in the picture below) but I don't know if there is a simpler way.
Can I specify all the tick values to get an axis where all the variations would be visible?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular linear scale with **more than two** values in both the domain and range, thus creating a [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) scale.

For instance:

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 5e7, 1e8, 6e8])
    .range([h-10, h/2 + 10, h/2 - 10, 10]);
```

Here is the running code:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const h = 600;
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 5e7, 1e8, 6e8])
  .range([h - 10, h / 2 + 10, h / 2 - 10, 10]);
const axis = d3.axisLeft(scale).tickValues(scale.ticks().concat(d3.range(0, 5e7, 5e6)))(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,0)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200", height="600"></svg>
```

Do not forget to make sure that the user understands the y axis is **truncated**, preferably with a clear annotation showing that.

Comment: Is it possible to add more domains? Or it's only limited to 2?

Comment: You can add how many you want, as long as you add the respective values to the range.